# WebElement (Radio Button List) cannot be found in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I have a WebElement in which cannot be found in IE 10 but works in FF 47.1 and Chrome 51.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "Foo's XPath")]
IWebElement Foo = null;
```

At runtime I have also called

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("Foo's XPath")));
```

But am receiving a NullReferenceException for IE10 Only. I have even tried a sleep as well. Can someone please advise me what else I can do b/c my program has to run IE.

As of the time this question was asked we have upgraded to IE 11 but am still seeing the exact same issue. I can't provide specific html code but I want to elaborate a little on the webelement foo.

The radio button which I have called "foo" is wrapped in the following

```
div 
  table
    tbody
      tr
       td
        input id = "foo"
```

When I call the xpath (I have tried id and css selector as well)

```
.//*[@id='foo_rblArgType_4']
```

the application itself defaults to the 1st value of the radio buttons and I can't seem to get it to select the 4th value which I need. Can anyone offer advice or suggestions of something else I can try?

Comment: You mean you attempt code works well in the all browser except IE rigth?? Could you manually found that radiobutton in the IE and click??

Comment: The only possibility that it does not work on IE is because the IE driver is much slower than Chrome or Firefox. I would suggest you to explicitly wait for certain time before finding the element.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of what elements are siblings you can have selectors like:

```
//tr[4]//*[contains(@id, 'foo')]

//td[4]/*[contains(@id, 'foo')]

//*[contains(@id, 'foo')][4]
```

You can also use the entire id if is not changing by replacing                [contains(@id, 'foo')] with [@id='foo']

If none of this are working then please provide the structure for all 4 inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try identifying element by id.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "foo")]
IWebElement Foo = null;
```

Also make sure that the element is not hidden. Also try increasing the size of the element as sometimes web-driver is not able to locate element.

If you still have issues performing any operations on radio button, try using JavaScriptExecutor. 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html